# Prove that the signs of a symmetric random vector are i.i.d. coin flips

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, independence

> Let $X=(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ be a symmetric random vector, where symmetric means that
> $$(X_1,\ldots,X_n)\overset{\mathrm{d}}{=}(a_1 X_1,\ldots,a_n X_n),$$
> for all $a\in\{\pm1\}^n$. Assume that for each $j$ we have $X_j\neq0$ a.s.
> Show that, conditional on $(|X_1|,\ldots,|X_n|)$, the variables $$\mathrm{sign}(X_1),\ldots,\mathrm{sign}(X_n)$$
> are i.i.d. Rademacher distributed (i.e. they are independent coin flips).

Remember that: $$Z\sim\mathrm{Rademacher}\iff\mathbb{P}(Z=1)=\mathbb{P}(Z=-1)=1/2$$
I proved that $\mathrm{sign}(X_1),\ldots,\mathrm{sign}(X_n)$ are i.i.d. rademacher distributed, so it remains to show that they are independent of $(|X_1|,\ldots,|X_n|)$.
This is how I proved the first part:
Let $A=(A_1,\ldots,A_n)$ be a vector of i.i.d Rademacher variables such that $A$ is independent of $X$, $|X|$ and $ \mathrm{sign}(X)$.
I am using the notations $|X|=(|X_1|,\ldots,|X_n|)$ and $\mathrm{sign}(X)=(\mathrm{sign}(X_1),\ldots,\mathrm{sign}(X_n))$.

The symmetry property above implies that $X\overset{\mathrm{d}}{=}A\odot X$ (here $\odot$ stands for componentwise multiplication). 
Simplifying $|X|$ both sides we get $$\mathrm{sign}(X)\overset{\mathrm{d}}{=}A\odot\mathrm{sign}(X).$$ Let $B=A\odot\mathrm{sign}(X)$. I showed that vector $B$ is i.i.d. rademacher distributed, thus $\mathrm{sign}(X)$ is i.i.d. rademacher distributed too. Infact, for all $b\in\{\pm1\}^n$ we have
$$\mathbb{P}(B=b)=\sum_{s\in\{\pm1\}^n}\mathbb{P}(\mathrm{sign}(X)=s)\,\mathbb{P}(A\odot s=b\mid \mathrm{sign}(X)=s)\\
=\sum_{s\in\{\pm1\}^n}\mathbb{P}(\mathrm{sign}(X)=s)\,\mathbb{P}(A\odot s=b)\\=\sum_{s\in\{\pm1\}^n}\mathbb{P}(\mathrm{sign}(X)=s)\,\mathbb{P}(A=b\odot s)=\sum_{s\in\{\pm1\}^n}\mathbb{P}(\mathrm{sign}(X)=s)\Bigl(\frac{1}{2}\Bigr)^n=\Bigl(\frac{1}{2}\Bigr)^n$$

It remains to prove that $\mathrm{sign}(X)$ is independent of $|X|$. I showed that $B$ is independent of $|X|$, but here I am stuck.

Thank you all!

Comment: Should the exponent on $\{\pm 1 \}$ really be $n$ (not $p$) so as to match the number of components in $(X_1,\cdots,X_n)$ ?

Comment: Sure, It was a typo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove sign($X$) is independent of $|X|$, it's enough to show
$$P(\operatorname{sign}(X)=a, |X|\le c)=P(\operatorname{sign}(X)=a)P(|X|\le c)\tag1$$
for every $a\in\{\pm 1\}^n$ and every $c:=(c_1,\ldots,c_n)\ge 0$, where the notation $\{|X|\le c\}$ stands for the event
$$\{|X_1|\le c_1, |X_2|\le c_2, \ldots, |X_n|\le c_n\}.$$
To do this, argue by symmetry that the LHS of (1) equals
$$P(\operatorname{sign}(X)=a, |X|\le c)=P(0\le X_1\le c_1, \ldots, 0\le X_n\le c_n)=:P(0\le X\le c).\tag2$$
Since (2) holds for all $a$ and there are $2^n$ such $a$, conclude
$$P(|X|\le c)=\sum_a P(\operatorname{sign}(X)=a, |X|\le c)=2^nP(0\le X\le c).\tag3
$$
Now solve (3) for $P(0\le X\le c)$ and plug back into (2):
$$P(\operatorname{sign}(X)=a, |X|\le c)=\frac1{2^n}P(|X|\le c)\tag4$$
Let $c\to\infty$ to deduce $P(\operatorname{sign}(X)=a)=\frac1{2^n}$, and you're done. (This argument gets you the distribution of sign($X$) for free.)

Comment: Nice job! Thank you very much, grand_chat